# How to implement toLowerCase in prolog?

Tags: string, list, prolog, return, ascii

So i'm trying to implement a toLowerCase in prolog but i am highly unsure on how to return or even work with strings and lists.  It seems all the conditions are rules are there, but i can't make it work so that i actually return a string back.  I keep getting that it's true and not returning a string.  This my code so far.

```
isUpper(H):-
    H > 64, H < 98.

toLowerH(H,R):-
   isUpper(H),
   R is H + 32.
toLowerH(_,_).

toLowerCase([], _).
toLowerCase([H|T], L):-
     toLowerH(H,R), toLowerCase(T,L).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it's not "returning" anything:

```
toLowerCase([], _).
```

This says that the lower-case equivalent of an empty list (empty string) can be anything. Obviously this is not true - it should also be an empty list.

After changing this to `toLowerCase([], []).`, the result will always be an empty list. This is because you never actually use the `R` you get from the `toLowerH(H,R)`. You should also be getting a warning about the singleton variable, which points to the problem. Let's fix that:

```
toLowerCase([H|T], [R|L]):-
     toLowerH(H,R), toLowerCase(T,L).
```

Alternatively, you could just replace this entire construct with a single [`maplist\3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/3):

```
toLowerCase(U, L) :- maplist(toLowerH, U, L).
```

Great, now we are getting output, but it is still not correct. Specifically, for input letters that are not upper-case, the output will be a free variable (i.e. some unspecified value). For inputs that are upper-case, there will be two successful paths: one resulting in the lower-case version, and one with a free variable.

The culprit is `toLowerH(_,_).`. This essentially says that anything can be the lower case version of anything. What you really want to be saying is that something is the lower case version of itself, if it is already lower case. Assuming that anything that is not upper case is considered lower case, we can write this as

```
toLowerH(L,L):- \+(isUpper(L)).
```

And now we get a single output with all upper case letters replaced by their lower case versions!

Also note that currently lower case `a`, which has code 97, is recognized as upper case letter. You probably need to update the bounds accordingly.

---

End result looks like this:

```
isUpper(H):-
    H > 64, H < 97.

toLowerH(H,R):-
   isUpper(H),
   R is H + 32.
toLowerH(L,L):- \+(isUpper(L)).

toLowerCase(U, L) :- maplist(toLowerH, U, L).
```

Examply query:

```
?- atom_codes('TEsT abc DEF 123456', _U), toLowerCase(_U, _L), atom_codes(O, _L).
O = 'test abc def 123456';
false.
```

Comment: what is maplist?

Comment: @christian it applies the predicate `toLowerH` to each pair of elements in `U` and `L` - or in simpler words, it applies `toLowerH` to each element of `U` and stores the result in `L`. It's basically a shorter way to write the same thing as what you had before.

Comment: oh okay, that's a handy function.  Thanks for your help, i'm still a novice at prolog unfortunately.